# Separate executions of BDD scenario outline examples in to different TestRail test cases (per example)

Tags: cucumber, jenkins-plugins, bdd, cucumber-junit, testrail

For reporting in to TestRail on automated BDD (cucumber-jvm) runs are using the Jenkins test rail plugin https://github.com/jenkinsci/testrail-plugin and we are getting false positives for test cases from scenario outlines.

The default implementation logs scenario outline example executions as multiple executions of the same test case in the same run. If the last example to run passed then the test case is passed for the run, even if all other examples actually failed.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour and did you find a way to change it so if any fail then the test case is failed or to list each example execution as a different test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would report this behaviour to the authors of the plugin. The behaviour you describe is clearly very wrong.

Comment: Yeah I've put a issue on the github project but it's not been updated in some time.. Workaround might be to uniquify the test name per example, just wondered if anyone had experienced this specific issue.

Comment: I'd suggest that maybe its a plugin thats not worth using. Apart from that good luck.